# Make Container fill TableCell in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a `Table` with two cells of the same width and height, so that the height depends on the size of the content. However, the smaller `TableCell` always shrinks:

[image: This is what I have now]

This is what I'm trying to implement:

[image: This is what I'm trying to implement]

Here's the code:

```
  Table(
    children: [
      TableRow(
        children: [
          TableCell(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                  'long text long text long text long text long text long text long text'),
            ),
          ),
          TableCell(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Text('short text'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

P.S. I could solve it by adding `verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,` to the smaller cell, but any cell can be the smaller one, depending on the content. When I add this line to both cells, the whole table disappears. The only bypass I could imagine is to calculate the length of the content and find the smaller cell, but I wonder if there is a way to implement this UI directly with Flutter.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: if this widget only use nth of items, like here two, you can use `flex` with Text instead of `Table`

Comment: `Flex` and `Row` unfortunately behave the same way, shrinking the smaller widget. They let fill the space only with fixed `height`, which is not an option in this case.

Comment: Will your widget always will be nth elements, like here two cells?

Comment: Yes, the number of cells is fixed.

Comment: I will prefer row in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight`

`IntrinsicHeight` limits the height of the `Row` to the content size, which however is considered a 'relatively expensive' approach and is [not recommended](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html).

```
  IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text(
                  'long text long text long text long text long text',
                ))),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Text(
                  'short text',
                ))),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

### 2. `Table` with `TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill`

As mentioned in the question, the `.fill` option must not be used in the largest `TableCell`, because in this case the `TableRow` will have [zero height](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TableCellVerticalAlignment.html). This is the preferred solution, because it doesn't have the 'expensiveness' issue of the previous one.

```
final texts = ['long text long text long text long text long text', 'short text'];
final colors = [Colors.green, Colors.orange];
// find the longest text and its index
final max = texts.asMap().entries.reduce(
      (a, b) => (a.value.length > b.value.length) ? a : b,
    );
return Table(children: [
  TableRow(
    children: texts
        .asMap()
        .entries
        .map((e) => TableCell(
            // use .fill in all cells except the largest
            verticalAlignment: (e.key != max.key)
                ? TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill
                : TableCellVerticalAlignment.top,
            child: Container(
              color: colors[e.key],
              child: Text(e.value),
            )))
        .toList(),
  ),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Since Flutter 3.18

*This is not released yet, only available via `flutter channel master`.*

You now have the possibility to specify: `TableCellVerticalAlignment.intrinsicHeight`

```dart
 Table(
    defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.intrinsicHeight,
    children: [
      TableRow(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('A'),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('B'),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text('C &\nD'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/130264